# How do I parse this JSON with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I had this structure in xml and I was able to parse it successfully. Now what I have done is that I converted this xml into a JSON using www.xmltojson.org but I am not able to parse it . I am setting these files locally on we localhost web server:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'feed.json',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'GET',
                success:function(json) {
/// what to do here
}.
error: {
 alert("Parse Failed");
}
});
});
</script>
```

I am trying to learn JSON, so I am little unsure as to where I am doing wrong, or even if that is the correct approah.

Thanks Mikey.

Comment: What do you want to do with the json ? the json parameter is already an object parsed from the json string you got from feed.json.

Comment: Show us what you did with the XML, and show us some demo data. Actually, there's not much to do; jQuery will automatically *parse* the JSON response for you and pass a plain JS object to your callback.

Comment: @undefined: My JSON is in the feed.json file.

Comment: @Mike I meant your JSON's data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to parse anything because you already specify `dataType:'json'`; If the url exists and returns a valid json string, jQuery will parse it for you, so the success callback would get an actual object:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'feed.json',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.propertyone);
            console.log(data.propertytwo);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Parse Failed");
        }
    });
});
```

(Also you had a couple of syntax errors in your original code, fixed above)

Comment: Actually I converted this xml to json http://www.codeplex.com/site/feeds/rss and now I want to parse that json and out them into an html page. as <a> tags and <p> tags. is that possible and do that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [**jQuery.parseJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: jQuery already uses parseJSON internally for json ajax requests so no need to manually implement it

Answer (score 1):

See an example:

`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');`

`alert( obj.name === "John" );`

Another example:

`$.each(json, function(i,e){`
`alert(e.data); // data is the key for value`
`}`

Answer (score 1):

you dont need 3rd party tools.

jquery can convert it for you automagically by setting `dataType:'xml json'`

> [...] a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert
>   from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and
>   then from text to xml.

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: can you post a link to your blockquote statement.

Comment: @Mike sure. here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: basically I need to parse feed.json and put the content into an html page. My json should give me a href link to open in new tag and a p tag that has description of that link. something like this http://www.codeplex.com/site/feeds/rss

Comment: @Mike to get the best from [so], you should set a jsfiddle with your code and let people edit it with working samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `dataType` to `json` then the json response will be parsed internally by jQuery and the parameter passed to the success function will be the object resulting from the parsed json.